# Python Django {'user': [ErrorDetail(string='Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received BoundField.', code='incorrect_type')]}

Tags: python, django, user-registration, email-verification

I'm developing my backend on Django. I wrote a code for user registration under RegistrationView class, and it worked fine before. I had to incorporate email confirmation in it, which also worked fine on its own. However, after all of that was done, I added some conditions to ensure proper working, but I get the "string='Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received BoundField.'" and "Forbidden: /api/v1.0/user/register-patient/" error.

Also, to clarify the workflow. Each user is assigned a JWT token while signing up. This token is different from the token sent to verify email. I named the latter "verification_token".

So a user signs up, their 'is_active' field is set to False until they click on the link received in their email. Sendgrid email API was used to send the email. The email is only sent if the patient_serializer data is stored in the db.

When the user clicks on the link received through email, their 'is_active' field is set to True, and they can now log in.

Also, the actual sendgrid API key is a part of the code, I removed it here.

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class VerificatonToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='token')
    verification_token = models.CharField(
        max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
```

My serializers.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from .models import VerificatonToken


class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VerificatonToken
        fields = ('user', 'verification_token',)


class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    username = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )

    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32
    )

    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        max_length=32
    )

    # DOB = serializers.DateField(
    #     required=True
    # )

    # gender = serializers.CharField(
    #     required=True
    # )

    # address = serializers.CharField(
    #     required=True,
    #     max_length=60
    # )

    # contactNo = serializers.IntegerField(
    #     required=True,
    #     max_length=11
    # )

    password = serializers.CharField(
        required=True,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True
    )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def get_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'token',
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_active',
            # 'DOB',
            # 'address',
            # 'contactNo',
            'id'
        )
```

My views.py file:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import PatientSerializer, TokenSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail
import uuid
import hashlib
from .models import VerificatonToken
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny



class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        print("API called")
        return Response("You did it!", status=200)


# Registering User & Sending Email Confirmation

class RegisterView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print("Registering User")

        user_data = request.data
        user_data['is_active'] = False
        print(request.data)

        patient_serializer = PatientSerializer(data=user_data)

        if patient_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            patient_serializer.save()

            salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
            hash_object = hashlib.sha256(
                salt.encode() + str(patient_serializer.data['id']).encode())
            verification_token = hash_object.hexdigest() + ':' + salt

            verification_token_serializer = TokenSerializer(
                data={'user': patient_serializer['id'], 'token': verification_token})

            if verification_token_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
                verification_token_serializer.save()

                message = Mail(
                    from_email='allinonehealthapp22@gmail.com',
                    to_emails=user_data['email'],
                    subject='Please Confirm Your Email Address',
                    html_content=f"Hi {user_data['username']}!\
                        <br><br>\
                        Welcome to All-in-one Health App. To finish signing up, please click \
                        <a href='http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/user/verify-patient/{verification_token}'>HERE</a>\
                ")

                try:

                    sg = SendGridAPIClient(
                        '<Sendgrid API KEY>')
                    response = sg.send(message)
                    print(response)
                    return Response(patient_serializer.data, status=200)

                except Exception as e:
                    print('ERROR', e)

            else:
                print(patient_serializer.errors,
                      verification_token_serializer.errors)

        return Response({'msg': 'error'}, status=403)


# RegisterPatientView() provides customized link to VerifyPatientView() in email to patient
# compares the token provided to verify the email

class PatientVerificationView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        print("Verifying Patient", pk)

        tokenObj = VerificatonToken.objects.filter(token=pk).first()

        user = User.objects.filter(id=tokenObj.user.id).first()
        if user:
            patient_serializer = PatientSerializer(
                user, data={'is_active': True})
            if patient_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
                patient_serializer.save()
                return Response('Patient email verified', status=200)

        return Response(status=404)


class PatientLoginView(APIView):

    # convert user token to user data

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        if request.user.is_authenticated == False or request.user.is_active == False:
            return Response('Invalid credentials', status=403)

        user = PatientSerializer(request.user)
        print(user.data)

        return Response("Testing", status=200)

    # authenticate user data

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print("Login class")

        # Looking for user's email or username
        user_obj = User.objects.filter(email=request.data['username']).first(
        ) or User.objects.filter(username=request.data['username']).first()

        # if user is valid, returns user data in credentials
        if user_obj is not None:
            credentials = {
                'username': user_obj.username,
                'password': request.data['password']
            }
            user = authenticate(**credentials)

        # if user is valid and active, logs user in
            if user and user.is_active:
                user_serializer = PatientSerializer(user)
                print("Login successful")
                return Response(user_serializer.data, status=200)

        return Response("Invalid credentials", status=403)
```

Postman request:

[image]

Command line:

[image]

**EDIT:** My TokenSerializer is basically the one giving an error. The Patiet_Serializer is working fine because the user info goes into the database with the 'in_active' field set to false. I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: In your `verification_token_serializer`'s data, change `patient_serializer['id']` to `patient_serializer.validated_data['id']`

Comment: Your answer was somewhat right. I had to make it `patient_serializer.data['id']` and it fetched the user ID right away
`patient_serializer.validated_data['id']` gave me a KeyError. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah ok, is `id` still on `PatientSerializer` fields? If yes, try printing what `validated_data` has.